# this is regarding Jquery/JS, if i change element's HTML - will i be able to perform other Jquery/JS action on it

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a a script that on click do a ajax call connect to the database get imagename and set the image name inside an < -img - > with the right path also it adds a hidden checkbox after it and then echo it.

i then take the ajax message returned and put it as div's HTML. my question is will i be able to preform more action on the inserted content..

The main goal is to be able to click on the image as if it were a checkbox(this part is already sorted for me) however no matter what i try i cant have a .click function works..

Here is the code.

This is the PHP part that echos the images.

```
if($_POST['updateIgallery'] == 'ajax'){
    global $wpdb;
    $table_name= $wpdb->prefix . "table_T";
    $imagecounter = 1;
    $toecho = '';
    $currentselected = $wpdb->get_row("query");
    preg_match_all('/\/(.+?\..+?)\//',$currentselected ['image_gal'],$preresualts); // images are stored with /image/.
    foreach ($preresualts[1] as $imagename){
        $toecho .= '
        <img rel="no" id="JustantestID" class="JustaTestClass" src="'.site_url().'/wp-content/plugins/wp-ecommerce-extender/images/uploads/'.$imagename.'">
        <input name="DoorIMGtoDeleteIDcheck'.$imagecounter.'" style="display:none;" name="DoorIMGtoDelete['.$imagecounter.']" value="/'.$imagename.'/" type="checkbox">
        ';
        $imagecounter++;
    }
    echo $toecho;
}
```

This is the ajax part that send and receive and insert the HTML to the div:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/wp-content/plugins/wp-ecommerce-extender/DB_Functions.php",
        data: { updateIgallery: "ajax", CurrentDoorIDnum: $('#dooridforgallery').val()}
        }).success(function(insertID) {
                $("#ImgGalleryID").html(insertID);
            });
```

This so far works what i am having trouble with is the following:

```
$("#JustantestID").click(function() {
//DoorImageGallery($(this).attr('id')); // the function i will use if the alert actually works
    alert("kahdaskjdj");
    return true;
 });
```

I hope the question and the code is understandable.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: I'm guessing the typos in the last piece of code are pretty obvious.

Comment: Sorry for the typos i will correct them,  i am going to test some of the solutions offered here and see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('img.JustaTestClass').bind('click', function() {
  var checkbox = $(this).siblings('input[type=checkbox]');
  if (!checkbox.is(':checked')) checkbox.attr('checked', true);
  else checkbox.attr('checked', false);
});
```

Comment: Pavel Staselijun your siblings worked perfectly for selecting the checkbox ..Thanks extremely. your whole solution was good as well..

Answer (score 3):

When you replace element's html, all the elements inside it are removed and gone. That means the event handlers attached to them are removed as well.

You could try attaching an event handler to a higher level element that is static and permanent on your page. Without more info I am going to use `document`:

```
$(document).on( "click", "#yaniv", function() {
    alert("kahdaskjdj");
});
```

Comment: so yours and adeneo answer worked now it does alert and i do get to the function . how do i reach the check box ?

Comment: @YanivKossas  does `$( ":checkbox", this )` inside the click handler work? I really don't know because I have no idea what `"#yaniv"` is :D

Comment: the yaniv is just a mistype / test i made but its the image id i changed my above code so yaniv is JustantestID.  i will test it with $ ":checkbox", this )

Answer (score 0):

Since the elements are dynamically inserted into the DOM with ajax, you have to delegate events to a parent element that actually exists when binding the click handler, which in this case looks to be `#ImgGalleryID`

```
$('#ImgGalleryID').on('click', '#yaniv', function() {
    DoorImageGallery(this.id);
    alert("kahdaskjdj");
});
```

Comment: How do i get to the checkbox select the checkbox within the function afterward then ?i mean i get the image id yes but wont i have to bind the checkbox as well ?